# Problemas ao animar sprites com javaS canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Estou tentando animar alguns Sprites Sheets, mas estou tendo um problema em relação a uma certa "sombra" que fica após o canvas executar o quadro da animação, ela seria o quadro anterior, não consigo arrumar isto.

codigo completo no JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/JScheuermann/syn8uyr4/.

Creio que o erro esteja no loop que não retira os dados do frame anterior, mas n faço ideia de como retirar ele do array, seria muito grato a qualquer ajuda que vocês pudessem oferecer.

Comment: Por favor inclua na pergunta o(s) trecho(s) relevante(s) de código, em vez de ter todo o código em um link externo. O exemplo no jsFiddle é bom como recurso adicional, mas o ideal é que todas as informações necessárias para se responder à pergunta esteja aqui mesmo na pergunta (sugiro [edit] fazendo esses ajustes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa limpar o canvas entre um desenho e outro:

```
this.draw = function (x, y) {
   canvas.context.clearRect(0, 0, largura, altura);
   ...
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/syn8uyr4/2/). Não entendi muito bem o seu código, então esse exemplo usa altura e largura *hardcoded*, é necessário portanto adaptá-lo para usar a largura e altura verdadeira do canvas.